# Making task bar icons consistently appear to the right of applications and places (gnome 3)

Tags: gnome3, gtk

My question is a highly specific one. I'm using version 3 of the gnome shell with the extension "taskbar", which displays icons of the applications currently running in the top bar. It's fantastic, but it's meant for the vanilla gnome shell, and I have two other extensions, applications (replaces activities with applications) and places. Basically my set up is gnome2. Anyway, with said extensions the icons in the top bar don't consistently appear on the right of the applications and places menus. It's an aesthetic issue, but very annoying. Right now they jump from left to right. 
I know I would be using gconf...